# Forward Exchange 2013 email to a different mailbox server

Tags: exchange, email-server, exchange-2013

Alright, I've seen a few of these posted, but nothing that really jumps out and seems like its' going to do what we need.

We have been using a cloud hosted exchange 2013 system for about 8 months now, but it went down and the cloud host was unable to properly bring it back up. We have some mail left (the DB is totally trashed so we're missing months of mail on the server) and we would like to be able to forward this email (manually by the user) to the new Cloud Host provider. In short, we have two Exchange 2013 domains, both using the same domain name with MX records pointing to the new cloud host.

I've read that I can reconfigure the send connector in the old Exchange 2013 setup, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I thought it would.

Thanks!!

Clarification:
So the original mail DB was destroyed. The cloud host provider then created a new email server with a new DB that has some mail in it (maybe a week or so) before we were able to move our mail to an internal machine while we setup our second cloud host -- yes this is crazy complicated and way over-board. we do not have access to the backend mail DB and the only access that was given was webmail.

We would like to be able to go to OWA, find an email, click forward, address it to ourselves, then have the new cloud host receive that email. All MX records are pointing to the new cloud host.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean `We have some mail left`? Where is the email? If the Exchange Server mailbox database is trashed then how are you accessing this email? What do you mean `we would like to be able to forward this email to the new Cloud Host provider`? If you mean that the email in question is in an OST file then simply export it to a PST file and import it into the new mailboxes.

Comment: The subject is misleading. This doesn't seem to be about Exchange at all but how a single user can use OWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the Exchange Server configuration, this question is not about Exchange Server but how a single user can use OWA to rescue a single email:

> find an email, click forward, address it to ourselves, then have the new cloud host receive that

Before answering that question I need to recommend that:

1. Have a suitable backup system. Don't let this kind of disaster happen ever again!
2. Think if there is any way to do this in masses.

   - If there is IMAP or even POP available, try to retrieve the mails with it instead.
   - If you can automate the previous to all users, do so. For example Office 365 has tool for migrating old IMAP/POP accounts: you can have a CSV binding new account to old accounts & their passwords.

If you really need to forward them mail by  mail in OWA your problem is not in MX record. The old cloud system has information of being the mail system for your domain. Therefore it only uses local delivery and the mail gets back to same mailbox.

You need to have another hostname that you can use for delivering these mails to another system. The new cloud provider may have this kind of hostname by default or you could use subdomain of your own domain, e.g. `newmail.example.com`.

Comment: We do have complete access to the exchange control panel of the old cloud host, but I agree with the idea of having to use another domain name to get it out of the system.